# Proving convergence of a sequence and series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am trying to prove whether the following sequence and series converges or diverges and if it converges, find what it converges to.
$$a_{n}=\frac{2^{n}+3}{5^{n}}; n  \geq 1; \quad \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{2^{n}+3}{5^{n}}.$$

I'm not sure what to do since comparing $\frac{2^{n}}{5^{2}}$ would be less than the original expression.

Comment: If $\sum a_n$ and $\sum b_n$ are convergent so does $\sum (a_n+b_n)$.

Comment: Note that $2^n+3 < 3^n$ for $n$ sufficiently large (in particular, for $n>1$).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n+3}{5^n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{2^n}{5^n}+\frac{3}{5^n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{2}{5})^n+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3}{5^n}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{2}{5})^n+3\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{5^n}$

The justification for the equalities is basically the one given by Kavi Rama Murthy in the comments, can you compute the two infinite series in the right side of the equation?

Comment: It is important to note that one must establish convergence of the two series on the right before performing this calculation.